# Solving $ \begin{cases} e^{-x^2-y^2}-2xe^{-x^2-y^2}(x+y)=0\\ e^{-x^2-y^2}-2ye^{-x^2-y^2}(x+y)=0\\ \end{cases} $ for $x$ (and $y$)?

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I'm trying to solve the following system:

$$
\begin{cases}
e^{-x^2-y^2}-2xe^{-x^2-y^2}(x+y)=0\\
e^{-x^2-y^2}-2ye^{-x^2-y^2}(x+y)=0\\
\end{cases}
$$

for both $x$ and $y$.

The problem is that from the first I can get $y=\frac{1-2x^2}{2x}$ and plugging this back says that $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Also, wouldn't plugging $x$ back into $y$ give yet that $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$?

I haven't tried the second one, but the first one seems to produce such confusing results that I'm not sure whether I'm attempting to solve the system in the correct way.

The second equation seems to give

$$y=\pm \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2}}{2}-\frac{x}{2}$$

How does this give me any way to find out any other solution than $x,y \not = 0$?

Comment: Unless there is a typo in the equations, just subtract them and see what you get.

Comment: @dxiv That way I get $-2x+2y=0$. I.e. $x=y$. But why does this solution allow for $x=0$ whereas the one above doesn't seem to?

Comment: Actually you get $-2(x-y)(x+y)=0$. Take each solution, replace in one of the original equations, solve for x, and verify whether it satisfies the given equation. The last step is needed because subtracting the two equations gave you a *necessary* condition, but not a sufficient one.

Comment: @dvix How do you get that? I subtracted first $e^{-x^2-y^2}$s and then divided by the common term $e^{-x^2-y^2}(x+y)$.

Comment: It's OK to divide by $e^{-x^2-y^2}$ since it can never be $0$. It's *not* OK to divide by $x+y$ (not unless you first prove that it can never be $0$). And if you do *not* divide by $x+y$ you get the equation from my previous comment.

Comment: @dxiv Okay. Also, do you think the method of subtracting the individual equations is the only way to solve this system? Or whether something can be done with the above solutions that I produced?

Comment: You *could* technically take the $y$ that you derived from the first equation, then substitute it into the *second* one to get an equation in $x$ alone. But it's a lot easier to simply notice the similarity between the two, and exploit it by subtracting.

Comment: @dvix Am I correct that $y=-x$ is not a real solution, because plugging that into the first equation gives $e^{-2x^2}=0$ which doesn't have a solution. Which would also be why the solutions $y=x$ and $y=-x$ need to be checked?

Comment: You are correct, on both accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{cases}
e^{-x^2-y^2}-2xe^{-x^2-y^2}(x+y)=0\\
e^{-x^2-y^2}-2ye^{-x^2-y^2}(x+y)=0\\
\end{cases}

Dividing both equations by the positive number $e^{-x^2-y^2}$ yields

\begin{cases}
1-2x(x+y)=0\\
1-2y(x+y)=0\\
\end{cases}

which can be rewritten

\begin{cases}
2x(x+y)=1\\
2y(x+y)=1\\
\end{cases}

Adding and subtracting them gives

\begin{cases}
(x+y)^2=1\\
(x+y)(x-y)=0\\
\end{cases}

If $x+y=0$ the first cannot be satisfied, so we must have $x=y$, which when we plug into the first we get

$$x=y=\pm \frac 12$$

Thank you to John Wayland Bales for the first part of this.